# Edison crosscompile

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, makefile, intel-edison

I am trying to crosscompile simple hello world from Widows to Intel Edison via cmd. Instruction from [here](https://gist.github.com/darylposnett/f11088a0ded82484a47e) works perfectly. But I wont to use makefiles and where are not exists i586-poky-linux-**make** in this cross toolchain. So I decided to use mingw32-make from mingw32 binarys for Windows x86. Here is my simple makefile:

```
main: main.cpp
    i586-poky-linux-gcc --sysroot=%POKY_HOME%  main.cpp -o test -lstdc++ -O2
```

And... Iam getting an error

```
C:\Intel\iotdk-ide-win>mingw32-make
i586-poky-linux-gcc --sysroot=%POKY_HOME%  main.cpp -o test -lstdc++
main.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:4: recipe for target 'main' failed
mingw32-make: *** [main] Error 1
```

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean to use `i586-poky-linux-g++`?

Comment: @perreal Error is the same. I tryed *g++, *c++, *gcc, etc. It's all the same.

Comment: can you find the iostream file in `%POKY_HOME%`?

Comment: @perreal Yep. I can. If I'll just write i586-poky-linux-gcc --sysroot=%POKY_HOME%  main.cpp -o test -lstdc++ -O2 in cmd NOT in makefile It'll compile and will run on edison.

Comment: I would try escaping the `%`s or quoting, i.e., `'%POKY_HOME%'`, and finally, try `$POKY_HOME`

Comment: @perreal Same. Doesn't work. Looks like mingw32-make cannot find this environment variables but cmd can.

Comment: Then try explicitly specifying the path instead of using POKY_HOME

Comment: It's works. THANK YOU!